# how can i get the website page title in asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I want to get the website page title . if i want to explain that what i want,please reading.
when you going to www.yahoo.com and clicking a link that have news title like this link

---

https://en-maktoob.news.yahoo.com/mahesh-bhatt-bheegh-loon-celebrates-unleashing-womans-sensuality-133609637.html

---

after the -----https://en-maktoob.news.yahoo.com----

we can see the page title that is ----

### mahesh-bhatt-bheegh-loon-celebrates-unleashing-womans-sensuality-133609637

my question is how can i get the page title after yahoo.com\ or any other website.

please guide me in asp.net 
after all thanks a lot.

Comment: you question isnt clear, are you taking about getting the page titles by scraping other sites? or are you taking about your own sites page title via javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. In this website you can ask spesific problems and get answers. There are many unclear thing in your question. First of all, how you will get the url you want to split?

Comment: yes i want to get other site
1- i have a url and my target website is online any time
2-i want to some code to return for me a title of sub page of website...for example www.example.com\news number one 
i want to get the text "news number one " from the url

very very thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the url is in a string variable then in c# what you need is Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

e.g.

```
    string url = "https://en-maktoob.news.yahoo.com/mahesh-bhatt-bheegh-loon-celebrates-unleashing-womans-sensuality-133609637.html";

    Console.WriteLine("{0}",Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url));
```

Output is

```
 mahesh-bhatt-bheegh-loon-celebrates-unleashing-womans-sensuality-133609637
```